# Time of day to go to the gym (cardio + weights), with regard to mental performance

Tags: exercise, cognitive-science

I am wondering what is the best time of day to go to the gym, and still be able to study efficiently afterwards/not forget what i learned that day?

Basically I can imagine myself going at morning, night, or 6pm (time of day I feel tired,and often have coffee).

*About me: struggling student who wants be fit, but academics is my priority. My question is kind of similar to: [Optimizing routine for peak cognitive and mental performance](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/10482/optimizing-routine-for-peak-cognitive-and-mental-performance)*

Comment: Go multiple times during the day in short bursts. You need that mental rest to digest information and exercise will boost your blood flow to help with it. (been in the same situation)

Comment: Thanks for contributing, I can definitely see you want to help people with their health concerns.  But this is another example of health advice without showing its evidence base (if there is any).  You're giving anecdotal experiences and advice without a source for someone to be able to evaluate whether it's legit or not.  That's not how HealthSE works.

Comment: thank you for contributing Ruslan, its clear DoctorWhom doesn't want me the get any response